# Tech stereo damaged by dimmer switch outlet, why?

Tags: device, dimmer, outlet

A low end Tech stereo was plugged into an electronic dimmer switch outlet.  The stereo was only a few years old and was functioning properly prior to plugging into a dimmer controlled outlet.  I plugged the stereo into a normal outlet after the incident, however, there is no indication of life.  If possible I would like to fix the stereo, but before hand I would like to better understand what component might be damaged, and why.  Example, could low voltage require higher current from regulator thus burning out the regulator circuit?

I have been put on hold due to asking a repair question.  15 yard penalty still 3rd down...  :)  JK  Andre's below response however was helpful, so glad I posted above question.

I researched my dimmer type "Lutron Maestro" which uses standard phase control, or leading edge.  Basically power is provided at certain time points within the AC +/-  voltage phases.  Different start times control light luminescence by controlling power on time.  A DC voltage can be supplied which does not bode well with magnetic transformers.  My stereo does not have a fuse from plug to transformer therefore the copper wire blew open.  I confirmed transformer input to be open with OHM meter, and I did not observe 120V AC at the input when plugged in.  Thought this might be useful for others who like electronic dimmers.  Bottom line do not connect a dimmer to an outlet as it can damage an electronic device that is plugged into it.  Good news though, transformers are cheap, and it is an easy fix.  My daughters Stereo is up and running.

Go Niners!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just a lower voltage what comes out of the dimmer. It was probably a *phase control dimmer* (as opposed to a *reverse phase control dimmer*) as they are cheaper and more common. This type of dimmer switches on in the middle of the AC cycle and switches off at the zero crossing and by this controls the average power that the device can take.

[image]
<sup>(red is the voltage after the dimmer)</sup>

The sudden rise of the voltage can be a problem for devices whose input is capacitive (behaves like a capacitor/has a capacitor parallel to its input) because a capacitor has a low resistance when it's empty and therefore takes a very large current when the dimmer suddenly switches on. It's possible that this just blew the fuse of your stereo.

Complex electronic devices in general shouldn't be dimmed, however more simpler switched power supplies (for lighting etc.) can sometimes be dimmed with a reverse phase control dimmer. That is one that switches on at the zero-crossing and then suddenly off in the middle of the cycle. On the other hand these dimmers cannot be used for devices with an inductive input because inductors (coils, e.g. a transformer) produce high voltages when suddenly switched off.

Comment: Great comment!  I believe the dimmer is a phase control, but will double check specifications.  I will also check to see if there is a fuse, that would be an easy fix.  Most semiconductor chips can handle 200V machine model, I assume this high of a voltage would not be generated from an inductor...  However, I am not sure if the transformer or capacitive load could be damaged due to such an excursion.  Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question.